# DiscordAPIError: Missing Permissions - Bot crashes instead of giving error message

Tags: node.js, discord.js, embed

**My bot sends an embed message that changes pages everytime you click on a react, some servers refuse to give the bot the "Manage Messages" permission which causes the bot to crash, I want the bot to reply with the error message instead or at least not crash everytime someone reacts.**

*Errors:*

**1.**

```
DiscordAPIError: Missing Permissions
    at RequestHandler.execute (----\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:170:25)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:93:5) {
  method: 'delete',
  path: 
  code: 50013,
  httpStatus: 403
```

**2.**

```
(node:4) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode).
```

Comment: Take a look at the guide [Missing Permissions](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/permissions-extended.html#limitations-and-oddities).

Answer (score 0):

Try to put a `.catch((error) => {})` block after your message like this: `message.channel.send(embed).catch((error) => {console.log("error");})`
Hope I could help
ShadowLp174